# Legend in a single line in d3.js

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

Following image shows how I want legend items in a d3 graph to be like. All items should be aligned with one line for all items.

[image: Here is the image which shows the how i want the image to be]

How do I achieve the above using d3.js?
I tried multiple times not solve this problem. I can not put put all items in a single line.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with what you've done so far? Without any code we cannot help you out.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/isuris/401/edit - Here is a fiddle that i'm trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you [**go**](http://jsbin.com/isuris/406/edit).

Just changed the `x` and `y` attributes of the legend and it did the work.

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("x", w)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 300)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - 200) + ", -50)");
```

Removed `y` and used the `transform` and placed the legend on top right corner.

```
legend.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    var g = d3.select(this);
    g.append("rect")
      .attr("x", i * 60)
      .attr("y", 65)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1]);
```

Here I changed the `x` and `y` attribute values to get the desired out.

```
g.append("text")
      .attr("x", i * 60 + 15)
      .attr("y", 73)
      .attr("height",30)
      .attr("width",100)
      .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1])
      .text(color_hash[String(i)][0]);
```

And finally amended the text with same logic to stay inline with the legend icons.

Hope this helps you.